# INSTALLATION _ PARTITIONING IN UBUNTU

Tags: partitioning

I have windows 7 ultimate in my laptop. C:, D:, E:, F:, G:,. Now C: have Windows 7 Os, D: is empty, E:, F:, G: have some important files. Now how do i install ubuntu in D:. I already tried but d: is permanently disabled in windows 7 os. NOw i ask step by step installation in my laptop installation path is D: is empty  with out deleted in my other drive files (E:, F:, G: - have some important files). I confused swap space when partition please help me installation ubuntu in my laptop.

Comment: Sorry but there are like - **thousands** - of Ubuntu installation tutorials. I'll mark your question as a duplicate, please read the question I'll refer to.

Comment: @EduardoCola - agreed. And installing without reading one is asking for data loss

Comment: When you created all these NTFS partitions, did it convert to dynamic partitions or do you have an extended partition with logical partitions. If dynamic you have to undo that first. Post this: `sudo fdisk -lu` and `sudo parted -l` from terminal in live installer.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu does not use terminology such as C D ect. It uses /dev/sdxy. You need to understand linux partitioning before you go any further or you will likely not install to the correct place.

Install guide is here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

and [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

For partitioning explained see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35676/how-to-choose-a-partition-scheme-for-your-linux-pc/ or similar such as https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/partitioning

[image]

Comment: First you said drives are in `/dev/sdxy`. Then you posted a Linux Mint image (in Ask **Ubuntu**) with bars saying `/dev/hdxy`. That may be a bit confusing.